# Посоветуйте как правильно реализовать программу. язык Java Что можете посоветовать?

Tags: java

Тема : Разработка приложения “рекомендации фильмов”
Описание: Написать программу, которая хранит базу фильмов с описанием их характеристик. Пользователь вводит критерии для поиска (жанр, название, год, режиссер), а в ответ получает информацию о подходящих фильмах. Приложение должно иметь графический интерфейс

Из каких баз данных мне нужно использовать для хранения фильмов ?
Стоит ли использовать компоненты JComboBox для критерий поиска (жанр, название, год, режиссер)?

Comment: Базы данных, элементы управления - лучше попробовать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

я в последнее время использую google sheets как базу данных, так как с ней легко работать и она доступна везде, обычно используют какой-нибудь sql. не понятно на какой платформе вы хотите видеть это. описание, характеристики, запрос - все java code